# Como adicionar um Chip (do tipo Filter) dinamicamente (via código) ? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

Eu preciso adicionar `Chips` do tipo Filter (imagem abaixo) dinamicamente

**Tentativa 1**

EU tentei criar o Chip de maneira totalmente dinâmica:

```
    fun onAddChip(name: String){
        val chip = Chip(this)

        chip.TYPE = Filter //Eu esperava que tivesse como fazer isso
        chip.text = name
        chip.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        chip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.marsala)
        chip.chipCornerRadius = 32F

        servicos_container_chip_group.addView(chip)
    }
```

Mas como é possível ver no comentário da linha 4, não existe como setar o tipo do Chip como filter.

**Tentativa 2**

Eu achei [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53703999/add-filterchips-programatically-in-android) um modo de inflar um layout pre-definido, o problema é que eu não entendo o que seria esse `view` que ele insere no segundo parâmetro. Eu imagino que seja um `chip_group`, então eu adicionei fiz do seguinte modo:

```
val chip = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chip_layout, view!!.parent.parent as ViewGroup, false) as Chip
```

e também não deu certo. Ele dá erro.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

*PS. Espero que o Maniero não coloque minha questão como fora do contexto, de novo!*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

**Achei uma solução que funcionou legal!**

Segue o [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557863/change-chip-widget-style-programatically-not-working-android)